# How can I correctly modularize Shiny web app?

Tags: r, shiny, module

I've been trying to modularise and clean an existing Shiny web app code but since I am quite new to Shiny, I've been using various sources of codes and videos to understand it but they were all done slightly differently so got me quite confused on how exactly to go about it. Below shows my progress with the modularisation - created modules for sidebar (contains 3 select inputs), tab 1 (contains a scatter plot), tab 2 (contains table) and tab 3 (contains definitions and trying to make these definitions show up in the server). Please note that I've taken away some of the text sections in the module ui for tabs 2 and 3 for ease of sharing. Is it possible to check if I am along the right lines and where the errors may be coming from?

I am mainly getting an error when bringing the ui of the modules together. I've also tried to run the modules on their own but that didn't quite work either so I feel like I am missing some key parts in the code. Any help on this is appreciated, thanks all.

````
summary <- read.csv("summary.csv")
results <- read.csv("results.csv")



####sidebar module
##module UI function
sidebar_ui <- function(id){
  
  #namespace function
  ns <- NS(id, "sidebar")
  
  #wrap in tagList()
  tagList(
    
    #Sidebar panel with select inputs  
    sidebarPanel(  selectInput("survey", label = "Select survey question: ", 
                               choices = sort(unique(summary$survey_metric))),
                   selectInput("usage", label = "Select usage question ", 
                               choices = sort(unique(summary$usage_metric))),
                   selectInput("team_name", label = "Select team Name from list:", 
                               choices = sort(unique(na.omit(summary$team))))
    ))
}

##module server function
sidebar_server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  #return reactive outputs  
  data_filtered<-reactive({
    summary %>% filter(survey_metric==input$survey & usage_metric==input$usage)
  })
  
  data_filtered_team<-reactive({
    summary %>% filter(survey_metric==input$survey & usage_metric==input$usage & team==input$team_name)
  })
  
  lm_eqn<-reactive({
    
    m <- lm(survey_score ~ usage_score, data_filtered());
    
    eq <-paste("y = ",format(unname(coef(m)[1]), digits = 2)," + ",format(unname(coef(m)[2]), digits = 2),
               "  R^2 = ",format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3))
    
    eq
  })
  
}



#####tabs module

###tab1 module
#ui
tab1_ui <- function(id){
  
  ns <- NS(id, "tab1")
  
  tabPanel(title="Results plot",
           strong("Survey year: 2020"),
           br(),
           
           #plot description                
           plotlyOutput("plot"),
           "....",br(),br(),br(),
           
           strong("Linear regression"),br(),
           "...."
  )
}

###tab1 server
#server
tab1_server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly(
    ggplotly(ggplot(data=data_filtered(),aes(x=usage_score,y=survey_score))+
               geom_point(aes(color=Group,text=team))+
               geom_smooth(method="lm")+
               geom_text(x=min(data_filtered()$usage_score),y=max(data_filtered()$survey_score),label=lm_eqn(),hjust=3)+
               geom_point(data=data_filtered_team(),aes(x=usage_score,y=survey_score),shape="diamond",size=3,color="red")+
               theme_bw()+
               labs(title=paste(input$survey," vs ",input$usage),x="Usage Score",y="Survey Score"))
  )
}


###tab2 module
#ui
tab2_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id, "tab2")
  
  tabPanel(title="R-Squared Comparison table", 
           strong("Survey year: 2020"),
           br(),
           
           dataTableOutput("table"), br(),
           "...",
           br(),br(),
           "...",
           br(),br(),
           "...",
           br(),br(),
           "...",
           br(),br(),
           "...")  
  
}

#server
tab2_server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$table<-renderDataTable({
    
    datatable(setorder(results,-`R-Squared`))})
}


###tab3 module
#ui
tab3_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id, "tab3")
  
  tabpanel(title="Definitions",
           br(), 
           strong("Survey year: 2020"),
           br(),br(),
           
           strong("Survey Definitions"),br(), br(), 
    
           
           br(),br(),br(),
           
           
           
           strong("Usage Definitions"),
           br(),br(),
          
           br(),br()
  )
}

#server
tab3_server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$tab3_ui
}




#####combined UI
ui = htmlOutput("page")
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Usage vs Survey"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebar_ui("sidebar"),
    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(type="tabs",
                          tab1_ui("tab1"),
                          tab2_ui("tab2"),
                          tab3_ui("tab3"))))
)



####combined server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(sidebar_server, "sidebar")
  callModule(tab1_server, "tab1")
  callModule(tab2_server, "tab2")
  callModule(tab3_server, "tab3")
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)```
````

Comment: I can't run your code since I don't have the csv files, but one of the problems I am seeing is that you are not actually using the namespace inside your modules. For example, in sidebar_ui, instead of `selectInput("survey"`, you should have `selectInput(ns("survey")`

Comment: @ginberg This was one of the main errors in the code! Thank you for helping me fix it.